# crontab not executing all lines

Tags: cron

I have a sudo crontab like this to sync time:

```
# m h dom mow dow command

0 6 * * * ntpdate 10.3.3.3 >> /var/mylog/ntp.log
0 7 * * * /var/mylog/backup.sh >> /var/mylog/backup.log
```

The problem I am having is that the first line (ntpdate) never seems to execute. If I run it manually with sudo that line works. cron does run the backup.sh at the 7, but it never executes then ntp sync at 6. The syslog doesn't seem to show anything.

System is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Running ntpdate via cron is almost always the wrong thing to do.  **Why don't you install the ntp daemon?**  As for your problem, check the PATH? give the fully full path to ntpdate?

Comment: You are correct, in that PATH is the problem. I dont run ntpd because this system is on a vessel that connects and disconnects at certain times having seperate timing in all the conf files of different daemons is a pain. Why is ntpdate via cron 'wrong'? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: `ntpdate` is deprecated; its functionality is now available with the `-q` option to `ntpd`. Since you have an intermittent network connection, it's probably best to run `ntpd -q` in a local script that fires whenever the network connection comes up, rather than within crontab. You'll also need to add `iburst` in `/etc/ntpd.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a cron job runs it does not have the full environment of a user, which means that the problem will be that ntpdate simple isn't found. To be sure you should specify the full path to a file to be executed in a cron task.